# Fitnesse - method name starting with unwanted "set" prefix

Tags: c#, testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I have trouble with fitnesse adding a prefix "set" to names of my methods and therefore not finding any. It does not do the same thing with a different method from same, which I figured is because said method starts with "get" so I guess there is something I am missing in the syntax since this keyword makes it act differently.

Fitnesse code:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner,C:\Users\Kain\Source\repos\mc\build\Tools\fitnesse\fitSharp.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\Users\Kain\Source\repos\mc\build\Tools\fitnesse\RunnerW.exe}
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path ..\..\results\WindowsHost\Acceptance.Tests.dll

!|Namespace.ConnectorClass|
| get connector schemas |
| ensure | has input schema defined |
| ensure | has output schema defined |


!|Namespace.ConnectorClass|
| send valid query | 
| ensure | is valid input |
| ensure | is valid response |
| reject | is error response |
| show | error |
```

Output:
[image: testpage screenshot]

Comment: Rather than obscuring everything that is presumably sensitive, it would be a lot easier to help you if you'd just provide a short but complete example which *isn't* sensitive... and show the code as text, rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: The blurred text is just a namespace with a class name, both of which are correct and fitnesse marks htem correct.

Comment: But it's much harder to understand how everything fits together with all of this blurring. Please be aware that the primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of good questions and answers, to help future developers. A short but complete example is really good for that - an example where half of the text is blurred out is *not* good for that.

Comment: I understand but there is no additional helpful information in those sections. All the areas contain the same namespace and I think are not essential to the question.

Comment: No, you don't seem to understand. Your question would be easier to read, easier to understand, and generally better, if it were in the form of a short but complete example, with text posted as text instead of as images, and nothing blurred out. It's not obvious to me why you're rejecting this simple suggestion of how to make your question really pretty *significantly* better. (It would also be better if it included the C# code involved as well. Basically *everything* required to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: OK, so I have entered the fitnesse page code as text and changed the output so it doesn't have to be blurred. Hope this is fine now :)

Comment: Much better - although including `ConnectorClass` as well would be even better. At this point it's in a better state for someone who actually knows Slim to comment...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the Slim script table.  So you need to put `script` in the first cell of your table:

```
!|script|Namespace.ConnectorClass|
| get connector schemas |
| ensure | has input schema defined |
| ensure | has output schema defined |
```

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable

Without the `script` cell, Slim is treating your table as a Slim decision table.